# How to update Ack parameter in Kafka Connect connector com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect.spooldir.SpoolDirCsvSourceConnector?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, kafka-producer-api

I try to use this Kafka Connect connector : com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect.spooldir.SpoolDirCsvSourceConnector to expose CSV data on a Kafka Cluster.

I don't see any parameter about Acks [here](https://jcustenborder.github.io/kafka-connect-documentation/projects/kafka-connect-spooldir/sources/SpoolDirCsvSourceConnector.html)

But in the logs when I create the connector I can see :

```
[2022-02-03 16:03:46,551] INFO ProducerConfig values:
acks = -1**
batch.size = 16384
bootstrap.servers = ...
```

I've tried to set acks = 1 in my config but it does not seems to work.

```
{
        "name": "CsvSpoolDirAutoAck",
        "config": {
                "connector.class": "com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect.spooldir.SpoolDirCsvSourceConnector",
                **"acks": "1",**
                "tasks.max": "1",
                "halt.on.error": "true",
                "topic": "test-csv-auto2",
                "input.path": "/kafkadata/spool/tmp/input",
                "finished.path": "/kafkadata/spool/tmp/finished",
                "error.path": "/kafkadata/spool/tmp/error",
                "input.file.pattern": ".*\\.csv",
                "schema.generation.enabled":"true",
                "csv.first.row.as.header":"true",
                "csv.separator.char": 124
        }
}
```

I don't want to update a "global" config of this Kafka Connect just update this property for my CSV Connector.

Answer (score 0):

> just update this property for my CSV Connector.

As of Kafka Connect 2.3.0, you can add

`producer.override.acks`

Also take a look at `connector.client.config.override.policy` of the Connect worker

https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connect